# Reading from HttpContext.Current.Session fails on multi server environment

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, session

Environment: IIS 7.5, .Net 4.0

I have a problem reading from HttpContext.Current.Session on a multi server environment.

First in my code I store an object in HttpContext.Current.Session an later try to read it again. The read (performed a number of times) fails randomly and I suspect it has something to do with what server the call hits. The storing and reading of the object is done through ajax calls and a colleague told me to store the object in Page_Load. I was fairly skeptic and as it turns out the problem has not been solved using this approach.

Storing:

```
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public Stream GetHierarchy(string invId, string zoomLevel)
    {
        Hierarchy hierarchy = new Hierarchy();

        try
        {
            hierarchy = businessLogic.GetHierarchy(invId);
            HttpContext.Current.Session["hierarchy"] = hierarchy;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hierarchy)));
    }
```

Reading:

```
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public Stream GetCustomer(string invId, string includeDetails, string zoomLevel)
    {
        Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)HttpContext.Current.Session["hierarchy"];

        Customers customers = null;
        Customer customer = null;

        if (hierarchy != null) {
            customers = hierarchy.Customers;
            if (customers != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    customer = (from e in customers.DiagramCustomers where e.InvId == invId select e).ToList()[0];
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer)));
    }
```

Everything is working just fine in a single server environment...

Can anyone shed some light over what kind of problem it is I'm facing here? And preferably how to solve it :-)

./CJ

Comment: Do you have the option of storing the values that you need in a database that all your servers can access?

Comment: You may need to use some kind of in memory cache then that multiple machines can access.

Comment: @awright18: but does it make sense to have a server cluster where session is only available on one of the servers?

Comment: You would typically interact with one logical database endpoint. Even if it was replicated you are still hitting one unit.

Comment: As it turns out backoffice has finally told me that the server cluster I'm deploying to doesn't have a session database (didn't even know that was possible) and that I have to deploy to a different environment. Hopefully that'll fix my problem. If not I'll come back here crying...

Answer (score 2):

Use Sql Server to Store Asp.NET Session State
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604